# How is 'if (x)' where 'x' is an instance of a class, not an implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-overloading, explicit-conversion

According to cppreference.com an explicit conversion function cannot be used for implicit conversions. As an example they have this:

```
struct B
{
    explicit B(int) { }
    explicit B(int, int) { }
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};
 
int main()
{
    ...
    if (b2) ;      // OK: B::operator bool()
    ...
}
```

I would have thought that 'if (b2)' was an implicit conversion and therefore not able to use the explicit conversion function. So what would be an example of an implicit conversion that wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: Implicit conversions are extensively documented on cppreference.com, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: An implicit conversion prevented by your explicit bool operator would be: `int x = b2;`

Comment: @paddy Wouldn't that be a copy-initialization rather than an implicit conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Contextual conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions)

> In the following contexts, the type `bool` is expected and the
> implicit conversion is performed if the declaration `bool t(e);` is
> well-formed (that is, an explicit conversion function such as explicit
> T::operator bool() const; is considered). Such expression e is said to
> be contextually converted to bool.
>
> - the controlling expression of if, while, for;
> - ...

Comment: Ah, so by being a contextual conversion that makes it not implicit. I had thought the two to be orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ 17 Standard (7 Standard conversions)

> 4 Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted
> to a Boolean value. An expression e appearing in such a context is
> said to be contextually converted to bool and is well-formed if and
> only if the declaration bool t(e); is well-formed, for some invented
> temporary variable t (11.6).

The declaration

```
bool t( b2 );
```

is well-formed because there is used the direct initialization.